# Parse Error invalid type for key fromUser, expected map, but got *User

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a parse class called User, another one called activity. An activity has a fromUser field that expects an Object. 
When i make a new activity, when saving i get the error

> invalid type for key fromUser, expected map, but got *User

The code im using is:

```
Activity *activity = [Activity object];
User *loggedInUser = [SessionService instance].loggedInUser;
[activity setFromUser:loggedInUser];
```

The other solutions on stackoverflow use pointers but i want to use an object so i want to get this working or atleast understand why it doesnt like my user object.
At first i thought it was my user object so i also tried:

```
PFObject *userObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"];
userObject[@"name"] = loggedInUser.name;
[activity setObject:userObject forKey:@"fromUser"];
```

but i still get the same error so i know its not the my mapping of my user object to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object in mapping is a dictionary, in my case, i need to use a pointer to the object in the database.